# How to proxy a websocket connection

Tags: node.js, webpack, websocket, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have this issue that I field with github.com/facebook/create-react-app:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8527

Basically I am proxying the webpack-dev-server with my own server. HTTP requests are fine, but Websocket requests will fail with this error:

> ```
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3016/sockjs-node' failed
> ```

since there is a Websocket server listening on 3015 but not 3016.

So I may wish to proxy a websocket request.  I can proxy an HTTP request like so:

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {

  // proxy to dev server

  console.log('path:', req.path);
  console.log('url:', req.url);

  const r  = http.request({
    method: req.method,
    path: req.path,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    port: 3015   // webpack-dev-server is listening on 3015
  }, r => {
    r.pipe(res);
  });

  r.once('error', next);
  req.pipe(r);

});

app.listen(3016);  // app listens on 3016 and forwards some requests to webpack-dev-server listening on 3015
```

does anyone know of a good way to proxy a websocket request?

Here is my attempt to proxy a ws connection: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1697

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a very stable and proven library `http-proxy`, it is used as a dependency by many others reverse proxies and load balancers and such. It supports proxying websockets. It is also very easy to use. Here is the minimal example from its [repository](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy)

```
httpProxy.createServer({
  target: 'ws://localhost:3016',
  ws: true
}).listen(3001);
```

Comment: thanks, I am looking for a nice implementation details but this is good